# Dropdown menu & rounded corners

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, rounded-corners

A quick query relating to rounded corners on a dropdown menu.

**You can see a sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/tomperkins/C5mTf/**

The question relates to the 'Help' button on the right hand side. I've specified for the menu items to have square bottom corners when on hover, which is fine.

The trouble is, I can't get the 'Help' button to have rounded corners on the lower corners?

Got me stumpted, any help really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Tom Perkins

Comment: I see rounded corners in the normal state for the help button. Chrome on the mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this selector:

```
#menu ul:hover #help
```

This selects any element with `id="help"` that is *a descendant* of a ul being hovered. Since the help menu is *itself* that ul, this doesn't work.

Switching the selector instead to:

```
#menu ul#help:hover
```

fixes the problem. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/C5mTf/1